# Does presentViewController clean up the parent view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my issue.

The App I am creating has non-linear navigation.

So I am implementing my own back button and doing my own navigation.

However, I am wondering how I should be presenting the next view.

If my navigation was linear, I could do:

```
-(IBAction)btnBackPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However that will not work for me since pressing back may not necessarily bring you back to the previous view.

Therefore I am thinking of using for example:

```
AddTaskViewController *add = [[AddTaskViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The reason I am not using Storyboard is because all my UI is made programmatically in code.

The worry I have with this is that I think presentViewController will just push the new view on top of a stack. Thus, if the user presses back, forth, back forth, he will eventually run out of memory.

Given my circumstance that I need non-linear navigation and all my UI is created in code, what should I use to present the next view without wasting memory?

Thanks

Comment: Did you know that UINavigationController has a method called `setViewControllers:animated:`? You can insert or delete view controllers in the stack, creating a nonlinear navigation system. If this uses too much memory for you, you will probably need to do a lot of "rolling-your-own."

Comment: @architectpianist could you answer with an example of this? An example of inserting the new one and deleting the old one? I'm having trouble visualizing how the navigation controller is accessed from a given view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct that the user will eventually run out of memory if you keep presenting Modal view controllers using

```
[self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

will only dismiss the top most viewController being displayed.

Instead you would be better off building your own container view controller and handle your own navigation. For more information read the "Implementing a Container View Controller" section in the UIViewController Apple documentation.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Anyway this could be done with a navigation controller? All I basically need is that at any given time, there is always 1 view in the stack.

Comment: Could I just pop the old

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

and push the new?

Comment: popToViewController seems like it might do.

Comment: popToViewController will work but it requires the viewController to already be on the stack.

Comment: -(void) showNextView:(UIViewController*)newController
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:true];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:newController animated:false];
}

Answer (score 1):

If you are still interested in a clean solution using `UINavigationController`, consider this design.

**Situation:** Let A and B be types of view controllers. A is the root, and B is a detail view which can push or pop to other B controllers.

**Goal:** We want to delete any B controllers that are not adjacent to the currently presented view controller, but maintain the hierarchy so we can recreate the views when necessary. Thus, the maximum hierarchy the navigation controller will know about is A--B--B.

**Design:** Make A the navigation controller's delegate. Give it an array of model objects which represent B controllers enough to recreate the views from them. Add to this array whenever a B controller is pushed, which A will know about from the navigation controller delegate methods. Remove objects from the stack when a B controller is popped.

On pushing a B controller, the A controller will take the navigation controller's view controller stack and (if it exists) remove the B controller directly before the one that was displayed before the push. On popping a B controller, the A controller will (if it exists) recreate the B controller directly before the destination controller and insert it in the stack.

**Example:** Let's say A has kept track of a hierarchy like this: A--B1--B2--B3--B4. By the system outlined above, the navigation controller only knows about A--B3--B4. When the user pops B4, the A controller will be notified and recreate B2, inserting it before B3. Thus, the new hierarchy is A--B2--B3. When B5 is pushed from B3, B2 is removed to produce A--B3--B5.

I realize this is a fairly complicated system to implement, so I would only recommend it if you had a large number of controllers and required the amenities of `UINavigationController`. Another solution that occurs to me is `UIPageViewController`, which allows you to provide view controllers on the fly.

Hope this helps!